# Fill a dataframe column with a default value where findall returns no matches

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to default to a string value where the findall method returns 0 or cant not find anything.

tried:

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['A']=='123',df['B'].str.findall('listofvalues').apply(', '.join), ''), 'N/A'
```

and :

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['A']=='123',df['B'].str.findall('listofvalues').apply(', '.join), '') | df['C']='N/A'
```

and a bunch of other variations.

```
input  
A      B  
123    A B C  
123    B C D  
123    X Y Z  
321    E B G  
321    H I B  

desired output  
A      B        C  
123    A B C    B, C  
123    B C D    B, C  
123    X Y Z    **N/A**  
321    E B G  
321    H I B
```

this works... i just want to combine it into 1 line

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['A']=='123',df['B'].str.findall('listofvalues').apply(', '.join), ''), 'N/A'
df['C'] = np.where(df['A']=='123', df['C'].replace(r'', 'N/A'), df['C'])
```

Comment: Try doing this transform spaced over several lines first, so you can see what each step looks like in isolation

Answer (score 1):

A nice thing to notice is that `.str` also works on lists. Instead of join you can slice with `.str[0]` on values where `.str.len` is larger than one.

```
(df['B']
 .findall('listofvalues')
 .pipe(lambda s: s.where(s.str.len() >= 1, ['N/A'])
 .str[0])
```